# Congruences with twin prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, twin-primes

Let $p$ and $q$ be a pair of twin primes, such  that $q = p + 2$.

Prove the following:

> $\exists$ an integer $a$ such that $p \mid (a^2 - q)$  $\iff$ $\exists$ an integer $b$ such that $q \mid (b^2-p)$.

I understand I have to show $a^2 \equiv q\ (\operatorname{mod} p)$ $\iff$ $b^2 \equiv p\ (\operatorname{mod}q)$ but I do not know where to go from here.

I was thinking of applying Wilson's Theorem but I'm uncertain.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)?

Comment: I have read through it but I still don't understand how to complete the question.

Comment: Note that $p\mid a^2-q$ if $a^2\equiv q\mod p$. That is equivalent to $q$ being a quadratic residue of $p$. What does the article say about the quadratic residues of $p$?

Comment: Given that $p \nmid q$, the Legendre Symbol $(\frac{q}{p})$ is equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

In a twin-prime pair $\ p\ $ and $\ q\ $, necessarily either $\ p\ $ is of the form $\ 4k+1\ $ and $\ q\ $ of the form $\ 4k+3\ $ or vice versa. In this case , we have $$(\frac{p}{q})=(\frac{q}{p})$$ which is exactly the content of the claim.